# Stop dired opening second window of already open directory

Tags: dired, symbolic-links

When I open a directory using dired and there is already the same directory opened in dired, a second one is opened with `<2>`. How can I inhibit this creation of the duplicate window and switch to the existing one?

I know that I can set dired to use only one window, but I just do not want to have two dired windows for the same directory.

Dired naturally does this when I open the same path twice. But I access the same directory via different paths (via symlinked paths), I seem to have the duplicates. How can I reuse the same window when I access the same directory through different paths because of symbolic links?

Comment: Pressing `RET` runs `dired-find-file`, which opens another buffer. `dired-find-alternate-file` reuses the current buffer, is that what you want?

Comment: Is *fired* a package? Or did you do the same typo 3 times?

Comment: This was the spellchecker...... fired=dired.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't this the default behaviour? When you say `When I open a directory`, what method are you using?

Comment: Have you customized any setting related to `display-buffer` or `display-buffer-alist` ?

Comment: No - but I tried just now to open the same directory twice, and it switches to the already open window. But I think I know now why I have the duplicates: when I access the same directory via different paths (via symlinked paths), I seem to have the duplicates. So it seems that dired only opens one window per directory. I will add this to the question (which is not a question anymore as based on a user error.

Comment: The condition you are describing, of having multiple Dired buffers for the same directory, can be summarized this way: non-nil `(cadr (dired-buffers-for-dir (expand-file-name DIRECTORY)))`. However that is arising, you can test for it this way.

Answer (score 4):

Using [dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus), which brings other cool improvements to dired, you only need to set the `toggle-diredp-find-file-reuse-dir` var to `t`.

Comment: I think the OP is asking to keep multiple dired windows, but not allow multiple dired windows visiting the same directory.

Comment: Yup - multiple dired windows, but only one per directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the `dired-single` package from Melpa.

This package, though, does more than what you asked for. It creates a `dired-single-magic-buffer`; it always updates the same buffer whether or not you opened the same dired directory.

You can read more about it on this [emacswiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredReuseDirectoryBuffer) page.

Comment: Yes - true. But I would like to keep one buffer per directory, but just not duplicates.